# Sitecore Multi-Site: Prevent page in one site from appearing on another

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've inherited the maintenance of a multi-site instance of Sitecore (v6.5) that we're starting to see some cross-talk of pages.  The content is structured as follows:

```
/sitecore
  /content
    /Site1
       /Metadata
         /Nav
         /archived pages
           /archived page1
       /Home Page
         /Internal Page1
    ...
      /Site2
       /Metadata
         /Nav
         /archived pages
       /Home PAge
         /InternalPages
    ...
```

For this example, site definitions are patched in such that `www.site1.com` has a rootPath of `/sitecore/content/` and a home item `Site1/Home page`, `www.site2.com` has a similar rootPath of `/sitecore/content/` and a home item `Site2/Home page`.

The content owners will move pages out from under the "Home Page" node to a folder called "archived pages" when they don't want them on the site anymore.

What I'm curious is if there is a way to prevent the following URL:

http://www.site2.com/sitecore/content/Site1/Metadata/archived1pages/archived-page1

Rendering.SiteResolving is currently set to true, so neither site should be producing links like this, but I'd like a way to have this sort of URL return a 404 without having to resort to writing a custom pipeline component. Am I missing a simple configuration to prevent this?

Comment: I think the answer can be found in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581933/sitecore-enables-accessing-child-node-around-parent/19585467#19585467

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, make "archived pages" folder item "un-publishable" on all sites, do a publish site (smart publish), now all of archived pages are not on web database, because the parent folder is not publishable, and you should see a 404 page when hit this URL:
http://www.site2.com/sitecore/content/Site1/Metadata/archived1pages/archived-page1