# Sitecore auto-generates multiple URLs for a single page; can this be suppressed?

Tags: url, seo, sitecore

I'm involved on the SEO/analytics side of a Sitecore project, and was informed today by developers that Sitecore will - by default - create several live URLs for a given page, exampled below:

- /en/section/page
- /section/page
- /Home/section/page
- /en/Home/section/page

From an SEO perspective, 4 live URLs pointing at a single piece of content is pretty bad, whether those URLs are referenced in content or not. Is there a way to suppress this behavior at a global level within SiteCore? Trying to work around it seems like it would involve a pretty heavy-handed approach to 301 redirects, canonicalization, etc.

Comment: I recently wrote a blog post about ensuring only lowercase versions of a URL are accepted. You could adapt the concept to include any restrictions you require http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/notes-on-lowercase-sitecore-urls.html

Answer (score 5):

What you're saying about URLs is technically correct but I think looking at it from a different perspective will help you understand a bit more what's going on and how to deal with it.

It is true that you can access "page" by each of those URLs as Sitecore will in fact resolve those to that item under normal circumstances. However, the settings in your project should result in that not particularly ever being a problem. The settings for the LinkProvider in your project should allow you to control how links are generated which will likely result in only one of the above options or something close to it being generated for each of your pages. The following code is the link provider section from the web.config:

```xml
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="true" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

You have a couple reasonable options for making sure that the multiple valid URLs for a page don't affect you from an SEO perspective.

1. Print out a canonical URL with your preferred valid path so search engines can take that into account (you should probably be doing this anyways).
2. Insert a pipeline after the ItemResolver that will ensure a 301 redirect to the correct path if a page has been reached via an undesirable path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - it seemed odd that there wouldn't be a way of addressing this.  Your answer at least gives me something I can take to the developers to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

From [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662106/2911685):

```csharp
public class ItemResolver : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        if (((Context.Item == null) && (Context.Database != null)) && (args.Url.ItemPath.Length != 0))
        {
            if (Context.Domain.Name.ToLower() == "sitecore")
            {
                base.Process(args);
                return;
            }

            Profiler.StartOperation("Resolve current item.");
            string path = MainUtil.DecodeName(args.Url.ItemPath);

            Item item = args.GetItem(path);

            if (item != null)
            {
                Tracer.Info("Current item is \"" + path + "\".");
            }

            Context.Item = item;
            Profiler.EndOperation();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this was created for an instance of 6.x.  It may need to be changed slightly depending on your version.  Your developers will need to replace the standard item resolver with this and thoroughly test to ensure it does not have any unintended side-effects.